# Adding External Library in CMake ( linux )

Tags: plugins, cmake, npapi, clutter

What is the simple process to add my external .so in Cmake. I want to know the exact location to where it needs to be added. And also for the include directories path. Please suggest the simplest way. I am a newB in CMake.

Suppose my external .so file is libclutter-1.0.so which is present in bin/res folder.

Please tell how can i add it into the CMake?

Comment: You will have to write a very simple CMakeLists.txt file and then use the cmake utility. The problem for a newbie remains how to write one such file. The very basic steps to write one can be seen in an example given in the article ["How to write CMakeLists.txt" here](http://preetisblog.com/programming/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt/). I hope that helps.

Comment: You mentioned npapi; is this a firebreath plugin, or are you just using cmake?